# Data import from C++ parser to Unreal engine Blueprints

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

for the first time I am developing something using Unreal Engine and I have a C ++ parser for a large amount of XML data (gps coordinates, speeds, angles, etc.).

What is the best way to transfer data from this parser to UE, so that later this data can be used with the Blueprints system?

Advise the sequence of steps or what specific things to look at and study.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Attaching a snippet of the XML data might improve this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data tables and [FillDataTablefromCSVFile](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/BlueprintAPI/EditorScripting/DataTable/FillDataTablefromCSVFile/)

Comment: The question is about XML, not CSV. Does this function convert the data between the two formats before it fills the Data Table?

Comment: It does not, however you can do it in some other program. I should've mentioned that.